# Homebrew installation of ffmpeg is not detecting librsvg-2.0

Tags: ffmpeg, homebrew

I'm attempting to use homebrew to build and install ffmpeg (homebrew currently uses 5.1.2) with SVG support on macOS (12.5.1, M1 Pro) . This requires the use of `librsvg` (homebrew currently uses 2.55.1).

During the (re-)installation, the process fails with:

> ERROR: librsvg-2.0 not found using pkg-config

The following was done:

1. `brew edit ffmpeg` to include `depends_on "librsvg"` below the existing dependencies, and [`--enable_librsvg` within the installation args](https://git.ffmpeg.org/gitweb/ffmpeg.git/blob/eacfcbae690f914a4b1b4ad06999f138540cc3d8:/configure#l264).
2. `brew reinstall ffmpeg --build-from-source` (`ffmpeg` was installed prior).

`librsvg` is detected as a dependency and installed prior to the re-installation of `ffmpeg`, as seen in its installation log.

Running `pkg-config --exists librsvg-2.0` returns exit code `0`. This is what [`ffmpeg` uses to check for dependencies at point of build](https://git.ffmpeg.org/gitweb/ffmpeg.git/blob/eacfcbae690f914a4b1b4ad06999f138540cc3d8:/configure#l1475).

Result of `brew config`: ([...] changes are mine)

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 3.6.17-57-gea0b786
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
HEAD: ea0b786[...]fc234e
Last commit: 10 hours ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: 3635b0d[...]a7df1b
Core tap last commit: 55 minutes ago
Core tap branch: master
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /opt/homebrew
HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 10
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.8 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
CPU: 10-core 64-bit arm_firestorm_icestorm
Clang: 13.1.6 build 1316
Git: 2.39.0 => /opt/homebrew/bin/git
Curl: 7.79.1 => /usr/bin/curl
macOS: 12.5.1-arm64
CLT: 13.4.0.0.1.1651278267
Xcode: N/A
Rosetta 2: false
```

There are no envvar overrides such as `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` as far as I can see in my session.

I imagine these are being set / changed during brew's installation process, but `librsvg's` folder is included in the path list within the env vars shown when the installation is ran with `-vvv`.

Oddly, I had ran through the same process about a month ago and it had worked. I'm not sure what's changed since!

The `librsvg` package can be found alongside all other brew packages in `/opt/homebrew/Cellar[/librsvg]`, and `/opt/homebrew/opt[/librsvg]`